Why is 37...Ra4 in Harmon-Borgov "completely insane"?
In the last featured chess game in The Queen's Gambit, in the following position, both Nakamura and Carlsen criticize Borgov's 37...Ra4. Carlsen says Borgov should realize that however much he wants to win, he cannot, so he should play to equalize and liquidate towards a draw. Nakamura goes further and calls the move "completely insane". However, neither explain in detail why, and Stockfish gives the move 0.00. Stockfish's principal variation (d=44) continues 38. b3 Nxe4 39. bxa4 Nxg3 40. Ne7 Qxd3 41. Nf8+ Kh8 42. Nfg6+ Kh7, leading to a perpetual.
[FEN "r1b5/2p3pk/3bNnqp/1p1PpN2/4P3/3QB1PP/1P4K1/5R2 b - - 0 1"]
[startply "3"]

1... Ra4 2. b3 Nxe4 3. bxa4 Nxg3 4. Ne7 Qxd3 5. Nf8+ Kh8 6. Nfg6+ Kh7    

What is so wrong with 37...Ra4?

is your suspicion that it's insane because of the variation you gave but then they didn't give this reason when they said it's insane? or what?

@BCLC they didn't give this reason, yes (in fact they barely cited any lines, as you can see from the video).

What is the position before 37...Ra4 ?

@Evargalo rook was on a8.

Just because a move doesn't worsen the objective evaluation of a position, it doesn't automatically imply there's a valid reason to play it.
Black has the choice between a simplifying sequence that draws the game with relative ease and a move that makes his life harder with no chance to win against any reasonable play by White. Black should therefore go for the simplification, even though objectively speaking both options lead to a draw with perfect play.
As you've checked yourself with the engine, Black need to calculate a somewhat complicated line and that's just against one of the many responses White could play against 37...Ra4. Of course in analysis we can take as much time as we want to figure out why of the alternatives leads to a win for White, but in a real game time and brain power are limited.

What's the alternative move that simplifies "with relative ease"?  It's not obvious to me but I'm hundreds of points below Nakamura and Carlsen's level.

@NoamD.Elkies Nakamura gave 37...Bxe6 38. dxe6 Re8.

I actually just remembered that this position occurred after adjournment, so Borgov actually did have time to work through the intricacies at home.

@Allure even with an adjournment involved, you could forget some of the lines or your opponent could find a way to complicate things that you hadn't thought of.
